# User-defined commands that call the same functions but with different arguments

Tags: vimscript, functions

I am trying to create a command that calls the same function but with different arguments, like the following:

```
def g:MyFunction(a: string, b: bool)
    if b
        echo "foo"
    else
        echo "bar"
    endif
enddef


command! -nargs=+ -complete=command MyCommand0 silent call MyFunction(<f-args>, false)
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command MyCommand1 silent call MyFunction(<f-args>, true)
```

But I get no output. I think the problem resides in how I define the commands but I don't know how to fix it. I read [here](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html) but it didn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are prefixing your function call with `silent` which effectively suppresses output of your `echo` in the function.

Remove it and see different output.

```
vim9script

def g:MyFunction(a: string, b: bool)
    if b
        echo "foo"
    else
        echo "bar"
    endif
enddef

command! -nargs=+ -complete=command MyCommand0 call MyFunction(<f-args>, false)
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command MyCommand1 call MyFunction(<f-args>, true)
```

Comment: Auch! My bad! Thanks!